# How can I display the value of my textarea?

Tags: html, textarea

My textarea has a value, but it is not displayed in the textarea, which is working in my input field...

```html
<textarea value="This text is not visible"></textarea>

<input value="This text is visible">
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Textarea doesn't  have `value` attribute. Put the text between opening and closing tags.

**note** : Don't forgot to add name attribute .

It should be like this

```
<textarea name="textarea_field" placeholder="Text enter here">This text is visible</textarea>
```

Comment: Ok, I understand, so I cannot use a textarea in a form.

Comment: you can use it in form and on submit it will pass the value what you enter the data between tags . and don't forgot to add name attribute else form not pass the value to next  page

Comment: Ah ok, I understand!

Answer (score 4):

```
<textarea>This text is visible</textarea>
```